# How to create a Sequin Sign?

Tags: physics

Beginner here interested in recreating this sign. Would I just apply a physics collision modifier to a bunch of squares and use the wind force field to recreate the flickering effect of the sequins?

[image]

[Reference - anim GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUN3I.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for you, but give it a try. Make 2 planes - Subdivide one by 30 or so, and scale the other down (I scaled by 0.1, then 0.25 again to make it "small enough" - you will be able to tell if there's any overlap in the next step)

[image: Geo1]

Add a Geometry Nodes Modifier to the large plane, and instance the smaller plane at each of its vertices by using the node setup below. For the Attribute Randomize Node, set the *Attribute* to *Rotation* to affect the rotation of each individual instance.

[image: Geo2]

To animate the "wall of squares", add a Value Node set to *#frame* (just type it in the box) and maybe use a math node (Multiply by 0.5 or so) to slow things down. Connect this to the Seed input of the Attribute Randomize:

[image: Geo3]

The movement is a bit choppy (due to only changing the seed value), however it still seems to replicate the video convincingly. If needed , there are further steps that can be taken to restrict the rotation of the squares to the X-axis.